# columns.values is not returning the strings

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with column name `msg` that has string values.

I am trying to get this values using:

```
df['msg'].values
```

But I am getting integers(problaby the index of the dataframe) and not the texts.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the output of `print(df.head(1).to_dict())`

Comment: Will you please provide a reproducible sample of your dataframe? `print(df.head(5).to_dict())`?

Answer (score 0):

*Say you have a pandas dataframe with column 'msg':*

```
 df['msg'] = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'purple']
```

*You can print just the string values with just:*

```
 df['msg'].values** --> **['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'purple']
```

*In order to print the index:*

```
 df['msg'].index.to_list()** --> **[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

*You can print certain string values by indexing. If you wanted the first string value:*

```
 df['msg'][0] --> 'red'
```

*Or last value:*

```
 df['msg'][5] --> 'purple'**
```